# device twin older version

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Im trying to store device twin using iot hub and it works well.

Would like to know if we can retrieve the older version of the device twin.

```
{
  "deviceId": "iot1",
  "etag": "AAAAAAAAAAo=",
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
      "telemetryInterval": 15000,
      "$metadata": {
        "$lastUpdated": "2017-06-16T20:39:12.7001169Z",
        "$lastUpdatedVersion": 10,
        "telemetryInterval": {
          "$lastUpdated": "2017-06-16T20:39:12.7001169Z",
          "$lastUpdatedVersion": 10
        }
      },
      "$version": 10
    },
    "reported": {
      "newState": "standBy",
      "$metadata": {
        "$lastUpdated": "2017-06-13T13:15:15.0133321Z",
        "newState": {
          "$lastUpdated": "2017-06-13T13:15:15.0133321Z"
        }
      },
      "$version": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Need to pull the older version of the device twin.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
deviceId = 'iot1'
and properties.desired.$metadata.$lastUpdatedVersion = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

the following screen snippet shows an example of the REST API for query device twins:[[image: QueryDeviceTwins]]